# Can someone Polymorphed contract lycanthropy?

Tags: dnd-5e

One of my players was polymorphed, and failed his CON save from a werewolf. He claimed he couldn't contract it because his "form" was simply a fake shell and not really his body since the Hit Points weren't even his, and that when he left poly the disease shouldn't effect him...

help please?

Answer (score 9):

If we are dealing with werewolves. Their attack includes the following:

> If the target is a humanoid, it must succeed on a DC 12 Constitution saving throw or be cursed with werewolf lycanthropy.

If the target was not a humanoid at the time of the attack, then the rider effect of the werewolf bite never takes place.

A humanoid polymorphed into a beast IS a beast until the effect ends. This means they are vulnerable to animal friendship, but immune to charm person.

The curse shouldn't leave when polymorph ends, it should never have even had a Constitution save to attempt to affect the target. (If the target was polymorphed into a beast and not true polymorphed into a humanoid)

Comment: IF the particular form of lycanthropy affected humanoids AND beasts, then the effect would carry over. But none of the Monster Manual Lycanthropes do.

Comment: Although I imagine, in this case, the question was specifically referring to the polymorph spell, the same question could apply to true polymorph which does allow changing into a humanoid.

Comment: I did mention true polymorph at the end. Polymorph doesn't remove conditions on effect or removal so as long as it was valid when applied it would remain.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

A similar question was asked recently: [Do diseases carry over from polymorph?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180925/do-diseases-carry-over-from-polymorph)

Changing form to or from via polymorph only makes then the stat block of the creature being polymorphed. Conditions on a creature stay in effect when they shift forms and that includes lycanthropy. Polymorph would be overpowered if it allowed you to ignore existing conditions as you could have a stunned, blinded, poisoned etc. creature suddenly be right as rain just by changing into a new form.