# What happens when a Polymorphed creature who was mind-controlled reverts to its original form?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, polymorph, charmed

What would happen if a creature who was polymorphed was affected by, for example, a [neogi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/neogi)'s Enslave ability, when the spell ended? Would the creature no longer be enslaved, since both its mental ability scores are different, or would the mind control still be in effect?

Comment: Hi RandalCandle, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] when you get a chance and visit the [help] or ask here in the comments if you need more information. This is a nice first question. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: This is perhaps somewhat related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/181999/what-happens-to-ability-score-changes-when-shapeshifted

Comment: Very related on [Does exhaustion affect a creature after it is polymorphed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94475/does-exhaustion-affect-a-creature-after-it-is-polymorphed)

Answer (score 5):

### The creature would still be under the effect.

Effects such as a neogi's ***Enslave*** action, like conditions, are not part of a creature's [game statistics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138800). Therefore, despite what you might expect, the changing of a creature's mental ability scores has **no bearing on (ending) such an effect**. Consider that the target of the *polymorph* spell retains its alignment and personality.