# Do conditions persist when a creature is polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, polymorph

For [spell effects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200390/75095), it has been established that the effects would continue for the polymorphed form of a creature. For exhaustion, it has been [determined as likely](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94475/does-exhaustion-affect-a-creature-after-it-is-polymorphed). For petrification, the consensus is that a polymorphed creature that is later petrified would [remain petrified in that form](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108407/75095).

Conditions are not part of a creature's game statistics that are replaced by polymorph, so what about the other way round: will a petrified creature that is polymorphed remain petrified? Is it true in general, that conditions on a creature would persist when the creature is polymorphed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139520/discussion-on-question-by-groody-the-hobgoblin-do-conditions-persist-when-a-crea).